# Übersetzung für "improved formula"

Tags: single-word-request

Ich frage mich, wie die Übersetzung für den englischen Ausdruck "improved formula" heißen würde. Funktioniert überhaupt das Wort "Formel" in Deutschem als "Zusammensetzung" oder nur als Kurzschreibweise u.Ä.?

Comment: I think you're referring to it as in claims like _"The new XXX shampoo with improved formula"_, right? That would be "mit verbesserter Zusammensetzung". "Mit verbesserter Formel" würde man als Werbespruch verstehen, aber nicht selbst benutzen.

Comment: Yup, that's what I'm thinking of. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 10):

Auf Deutsch würden wir wahrscheinlich *verbesserte Rezeptur* verwenden.

Comment: Vor allem bei Lebensmitteln liest man eigentlich immer "Verbesserte Rezeptur".

Comment: Ja, viel besser als "Zusammensetzung".

Answer (score 8):

### verbesserte Formel

Vor allem Waschmittel werden immer wieder mit »verbesserter Formel« beworben:

[image] [image]

Das Wort »Formel« hat laut [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Formel) im Deutschen vier Bedeutungen:

1. Mathematik, Naturwissenschaften: Buchstabengleichung, Ausdruck zur Berechnung einer Größe
2. Chemie: Folge von Symbolen zur Beschreibung des Aufbaus eines Stoffes
3. verfestigter sprachlicher Ausdruck, feststehende Redewendung
4. Motorsport: durch Verbände festgelegte Durchführungsbestimmungen einer Klasse und deren Fahrzeuge im Motorsport, z. B. Formel 1, 2, 3 oder auch V

Wiktionary scheint die hier vorliegende Bedeutung übersehen zu haben:

5. Mischungen: Zusammensetzung, Rezeptur

Comment: Ich glaube eher, dass die Werber mit "verbesserter Formel" den Bezug zu den unermüdlich arbeitenden Chemikern herstellen wollen, die eine "Waschformel" erstellt haben, die besonders gut ist. In diesem Falle wäre das dann im Bereich "2. Chemie: ..." anzusiedeln. Außerdem kommt es bei Kunden immer gut an, wenn man von einer "Formel" statt einer "Rezeptur" spricht, denn so transportiert man das Gefühl, dass da Leute sind, die wirklich forschen. "Rezeptur" klingt eher nach Tütensuppe :-)

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: Nein, das verstehe ich nicht so. Der Teil 2-Chemie ist in Wahrheit nur ein Spezialfall von 5-Mischung. Das ist nämlich ein Fall, bei dem die zusammengemischten Substanzen sich in einer chemischen Reaktion zu einer neuen Substanz verbinden.

Comment: Ich meinte das auch eher ein bisschen augenzwinkernd, da ich das generell alles für Marketing-Blabla halte. Auch "Verbesserte Rezeptur" heißt normalerweise nichts anderes als: "Wir mussten uns was ausdenken, wie wir für weniger Inhalt mehr Geld nehmen können"...

Comment: Wenn ich aber auch sowas wie "5 Einheiten Weißkraftverstärker + 3 Einheiten Farbkonservierungsperlen + 2 Einheiten Duftkugeln" als Formel akzeptiere, dann ist eventuell aus olfaktorischer Sicht "4 Einheiten .. + 3 Einheiten ... + 3 Einheiten Duftkugeln" eine verbesserte Formel.

Comment: Volle Zustimmung